# What is the origin of the word "assassin"?

Tags: etymology

Etymological sources that I've looked at variously state that it comes from either *hashshāshīn* ("those who consume hashish") or *asāsiyyūn* ("those of principle"), both from Arabic. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_Assassins#Etymology) seems to be saying both origins are true, which is even more confusing.

Which is the true origin for the word "assassin"?

Comment: See also: https://www.etymonline.com/word/assassin - https://www.jstor.org/stable/3087895

Comment: None of those answer the question - the first is just one of the differing sources I mentioned in my question and the second asks a completely different question whose answer again links to one of those sources. Nothing I've seen so far actually mentions both of the two etymologies and concludes which one is correct.

Comment: I learned it's Farsi in origin, like jasmine, balcony and tapestry.

Comment: @YosefBaskin The Nizari Ismailis ruled both Syria and Persia, but all sources I've seen seem to give Arabic as the source which Latin derived it from.

Comment: I think some of those links have some slightly incorrect information.  The Arabic words are أَسَاسِيِّين (ˀasāsiyyīna “people who are faithful to the foundation [of the faith]”) and حشاشين ((ḥaššāšīn, “hashish users; low-lives”).  The two words sound quite different in Classical Arabic with different phonemic structures and suffixes.  Also, all of Arabic, Italian, and French have different phonemes for the sibiliants (/s/ and /š/) and so confusion between the two would need to be motivated by something.

Comment: The Assassins were Shiites living in Persia and Syria, 1090-1275. *English from Latin from Arabic* does not in itself say that Arabic did not use the Farsi word. People think of *Baksheesh* as Egyptian when it's Turkish.